How to Migrate Resources Between Azure Data Factories When ARM Template Exceeds 4MB Limit?
I’m trying to migrate all resources from one Azure Data Factory to another. However, my ARM template exceeds the 4MB limit, preventing me from importing it.
Has anyone encountered this issue before? What are some alternative methods or best practices to achieve this migration without hitting the size limit? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Can you share the code if tried any? @vw96

Linked Resource Manager templates with CI/CD
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery-linked-templates
